# Only first letter is being assigned to array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have a shopping cart ($_SESSION[cart_array]).  I want to populate a select/option list with just the unique GroupName field from that array.

My approach was to 1) create a new array with just the GroupName field, and then 2)create a third array that has just the unique values using array_unique().

I recognize that this may not be the most efficient manner, and welcome suggestions.

However, before I even reached that point, I had a more basic problem. I seem to only be assigning the first letter of the variable.

```
$GroupNames = array();
foreach($_SESSION[cart_array] as $h) {
    echo $h['GroupName']."<br>";
    $GroupNames[] = $h['GroupName'];
}

foreach ($GroupNames as $entry) {

    echo $entry['GroupName'] . "<br>";

}
print_r($GroupNames);
```

The output of the code above is:
Crystal Farm

Java Garden Batiks

Java Garden Batiks

Java Garden Batiks

Crystal Farm - Precuts

Crystal Farm - Precuts

C

J

J

J

C

C

Array ( [0] => Crystal Farm [1] => Java Garden Batiks [2] => Java Garden Batiks [3] => Java Garden Batiks [4] => Crystal Farm - Precuts [5] => Crystal Farm - Precuts )

My research makes it seem that I'm not declaring $GroupName as an array, but it looks to me like I am.  So, I'm lost.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be `echo $entry`, not `echo $entry['GroupName']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$GroupNames[] = $h['GroupName'];
```

Is literally building an array of group names eg:

```
$GroupNames = array(
   "group1",
   "group2"
)
```

But then you do this

```
foreach ($GroupNames as $entry) {
    // This bit is looking for a key which does not exist.
    echo $entry['GroupName'] . "<br>"; 
    //Instead try
    echo $entry . "<br>";

}
```

OR, maybe you actually do want a multidimensional array. In which cause when building it here:

```
foreach($_SESSION[cart_array] as $h) {        
    $GroupNames[] = $h['GroupName']; //current
    // You want the following
    $GroupNames[] = array("GroupName" => $h['GroupName']);
}
```

However, with the current example I think I'd go with option 1.